# Iterating more quickly, shorter feedback cycles, general workflow practices

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-cleaning, training

(caveat: I've not written that much ML code yet)

When I'm writing non-ML code I like to create short feedback loops to check the validity of my code. I use unit-tests or sometimes short helper tools (like psql scripts) to quickly give me feedback on whether I'm going in the right direction and whether the last change I've made is a step in that direction.

When writing ML-code the feedback cycle is often a lot longer, some examples.

### Example 1

When I'm training a model I first prepare (clean and validate) training sets. Knowing whether I've done a good (enough) job cleaning and validating the training sets comes after the model has been trained and applied to a task. This feedback cycle can take many minutes if not hours.

### Example 2

When I'm training a model I'll want to iterate on the different training parameters. Knowing whether those parameters have the desired effect on the subsequent model comes after the model has been trained and applied to a task. This feedback cycle can take many minutes if not hours.

### Example 2a

When I'm training a model and the training is done in several different training steps each of which can have different parameters and more input there's a lot of knobs and dials I can tweak. Knowing whether those parameters have the desired effect on the subsequent model (often) comes after all of the training steps are done, the model has been trained and applied to a task. This feedback cycle can take hours.

## Solutions

### Smaller training datasets

I could make the feedback loop shorter by using smaller datasets for training. However, I'm not sure how to determine whether a training set is still large enough to accurately reflect how a model would perform when trained on a larger training dataset.

### Parallel training

I could prepare multiple training datasets and combinations of parameters at the same time and then train all of them in parallel, or in sequence and get lunch. This does feel a bit like randomly throwing options at the model to see what works and what doesn't. It's not actual informed iteration, I think.

### Question

How do you time-efficiently iterate on the training of ML models? What are your workflows in this? Based on what do you make decisions wrt size of training sets etc?

If I'm asking the wrong question, or approaching this from a strange angle: please enlighten me.

Thanks!